# Xamarin ListView not show json results from api

Tags: xamarin

same as title,my listview doesn't show me anything,i think my model in that app is not good
help! deseeerialized json in jsonObject then create a list of objectModel but not show me
thanks

```
public class Marvel
{
}
public class TextObject
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Url
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Series
{
    public string resourceURI { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Variant
{
    public string resourceURI { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Date
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
}

public class Price
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
}

public class Thumbnail
{
    public string path { get; set; }
    public string extension { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string path { get; set; }
    public string extension { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string resourceURI { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string role { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Creators
{
    public int available { get; set; }
    public string collectionURI { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    public int returned { get; set; }
}

public class Characters
{
    public int available { get; set; }
    public string collectionURI { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    public int returned { get; set; }
}

public class Stories
{
    public int available { get; set; }
    public string collectionURI { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
    public int returned { get; set; }
}

public class Events
{
    public int available { get; set; }
    public string collectionURI { get; set; }
    public List<object> items { get; set; }
    public int returned { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int digitalId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public int issueNumber { get; set; }
    public string variantDescription { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public DateTime modified { get; set; }
    public string isbn { get; set; }
    public string upc { get; set; }
    public string diamondCode { get; set; }
    public string ean { get; set; }
    public string issn { get; set; }
    public string format { get; set; }
    public int pageCount { get; set; }
    public List<TextObject> textObjects { get; set; }
    public string resourceURI { get; set; }
    public List<Url> urls { get; set; }
    public Series series { get; set; }
    public List<Variant> variants { get; set; }
    public List<object> collections { get; set; }
    public List<object> collectedIssues { get; set; }
    public List<Date> dates { get; set; }
    public List<Price> prices { get; set; }
    public Thumbnail thumbnail { get; set; }
    public List<Image> images { get; set; }
    public Creators creators { get; set; }
    public Characters characters { get; set; }
    public Stories stories { get; set; }
    public Events events { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public int offset { get; set; }
    public int limit { get; set; }
    public int total { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
}

public class Rooto
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string copyright { get; set; }
    public string attributionText { get; set; }
    public string attributionHTML { get; set; }
    public string etag { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

}

mainpage

```
 private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var texto = caja.Text;
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
        request.RequestUri = new Uri("https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics?title=hulk&ts=1&apikey=###&hash=###");
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
        request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
        
        var client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Result dataObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Result>(content);

        JObject myJObject = JObject.Parse(content);
        Console.WriteLine(myJObject);

        List<Result> parsedFields = new List<Result>();
        parsedFields.Add(dataObjects);
        
        ListDemo.ItemsSource = parsedFields;
```

my xaml and json

https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/comics?title=hulk&ts=1&apikey=ab07bf416406297274b27ca941ba3bee&hash=cf9eb501d7c3775c32b72c61a6a76805

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>

        <Label Text="Control ListView"  FontSize="40" 

       HorizontalOptions="Center" 

       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Button Text="Lamado API" Clicked="Button_Clicked"/>
        <Entry x:Name="caja" Text=""/>

        <ListView x:Name="ListDemo">

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>

                <DataTemplate>

                    <ViewCell>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">

                            <Image Source="{Binding resourceURI}" 

                               WidthRequest="50" 

                               HeightRequest="50"/>

                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

                                <Label Text="{Binding title}" 

                                   FontSize="15" TextColor="Blue"/>

                                <Label Text="{Binding isbn}" 

                                   FontSize="12" TextColor="Fuchsia"/>

                            </StackLayout>

                        </StackLayout>

                    </ViewCell>

                </DataTemplate>

            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

tnaka

Comment: First, you've posted a bunch of your API keys to a public website.  Not a good idea.  Second, when posting code please remove all the extraneous junk, like the many many lines of commented out code that make it unreadable.  Third, what debugging have you done to narrow down the problem?  Does your json get retrieved from the url correctly?  Does it get deserialized into C# objects correctly?  At what stage of the process is it breaking down?  Knowing that helps narrow down the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

You try binding it to an observablecollection.

```
private ObservableCollection<Result> _parsedFields = new ObservableCollection<Result>();

public ObservableCollection<Result> ParsedFields {

     get{ return _parsedFields;}
     set{ 
          _parsedFields = value ;
          OnPropertyChanged("ParsedFields"); 
        }
}
```

make sure to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

then in your button function:

```
var dataObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ObservableCollection<Result>>(content);

ParsedFields = dataObjects;
ListDemo.ItemsSource = ParsedFields;
```

Comment: Thanks! i tried dont't work appear error JArray[1,2,3]

Comment: thanks! works for me,how to show images?

Comment: did it worked for your? if yeas please accept my answer else ask for more details

Answer (score 0):

The root level is supposed to be `Root` not `Result` class .

Modify your code as below

```cs
Root dataObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(text);         
ListDemo.ItemsSource = dataObjects.data.results;
```

Comment: how to show images?

Comment: The image url is not public, you can try it in browser first , e,g `http://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/creators/12712` , the url should be accessible from browser .

Comment: hi, ho do i can show another json atributes?can't do it

Comment: which part of the json attributes ? `dataObjects ` is a `Root` object , you can get any other attributes  from its properties.